# Magento Purchase event trigger to access a script file and supplies inputed variables

Tags: magento, events, triggers

I'm setting up an online store using Magento.  One of the things purchasable will Mumble servers (ftp accounts and other web things will be done, but the main issue is mumble as it needs to be automatic and immediate.

Here is how it's going to work.  First off we have a personally made server script.  At the moment I don't have the script file for me to post but I can add that later.

1. User purchases Mumble server from store with variables they select from drop down lists and input fields.
   [ex/ 30 slots; quality: 90kbps; clan acronym: NFC; superuser password: password5; your email: supercool55@gmail.com]
2. Purchase triggers server script and provides the script with the variables selected / inputed from the text boxes.
3. Server script copies the Mumble Server files to a folder and sets up the server as asked and randomly selects a port.
4. Email is sent to the customer, supercool55@gmail.com, giving them their selected options, their SU password, and the address to their mumble server. [ex/ 69.547.99.101:25565]

I don't have the web store up yet as I haven't bought the domain yet, but I do have a test one up.  The server exists already.

The script is already made, the biggest issue to me is how to have Magento talk to the script on a specific item purchase AND provide the variables selected.

I'll talk to my partner with this about his script and see if he can also include a new script that records the randomly selected port and credentials and has the server sends an email to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Magento event observer on some event for the order (actually, completing payment would be a good one here). When that event fires, have the observer invoke your server script through whatever standard means (fork, by URL, etc etc).

The place where most people get tripped up here is that some payment methods may make it difficult to tell when an order has been properly 'completed' and should trigger your custom code. Make sure to test the order flow for all payment methods etc before going live and getting surprised.